# Doctrine: Explicitly giving primary key value while not changing the auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a table with many columns along with primary key column 'id' having auto increment attribute.
The database is mySQL.

There are two kinds of PHP code that are inserting in that column.
1.) Normal insert queries are created as string and are executed by making ADO connection to the database.In this case, primary key value is not provided so it uses the table's auto increment value.

2.) There is an php symfony doctrine's entity class with primary field declared as

```
/**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;
```

The insertion uses the entity manager's persist method.
Here while inserting, **the id value is explicitly provided** which is far greater than the column's auto increment value. That's why the Generation_Type is ommited in the annotations.

Now, let's say the current auto_increment value is 10000.
I want that while executing the first scenario, the next id is taken as 1001 which is expected.
But in case of executing the second scenario with explicit id = 2000, it inserts the record with 2000 but does not change the auto_increment to 2000. It should still remain to 1001.

Do I have to make changes around this piece of code?

```
$this->em->persist(obj);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds like bugs that will be hard to find in a few month

Comment: Well, there are two flows in the system. The first flow uses scenario 1 which still insert the queries using auto increment value of `id` column. 
The second flow which is also the new one and uses scenario 2, is actually a part of REST API. The client that consumes this API will send id explicitly in the payload, though this id will be far greater than the current maximum value in the `id` column.
I want that scenario 1 will still keep using the auto increment value and scenario 2 uses the id that it gets from its client.

Comment: I get your use-case and it actually can bei done by manipulating the class metadata of the entity at runtime BUT you absolutely should not do this! And here's a reason why: The Auto-Increment value in mySQL is not persisted and and will be determined on db startup by selecting the max value of the id column and setting it to the next value. I don't know if you can circumvent this in any way but after you inserted a high id entry after the next startup you'll run into problems.

Comment: Additional Info: The resetting of auto-increment value behaviour changed with mySQL 5.8 so depending on your mysql version you may be okay doing it. Here's some more information about this change and possible problems: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3488-mysql-5-7-innodb-auto-increment-counters-get-reset-after-mysql-service-restart.htm

Comment: I'm using mySQL 5.8 version. 
As you said that this can be done by manipulating the class metadata of entity, Can you please provide some example code so that I can study on it and compare the different approaches of handling it?

And btw, thanks for the blog that you have shared.

Comment: I still think it would be better to add a column for an 'external id'. Had something similar in an old project. "this value will never be reached" they said. Guess what happened...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need your Doctrine Entity to ever use the `AUTO` strategy to set the Id value you should simply be able to use the `NONE` strategy

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $id;
```

More infos on the available strategies can be found here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies

If you need your Entity to have an auto increment strategy in the normal workflow you can set it to `AUTO` and disable that at a needed time by:

```
$metadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
$metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

General disclaimer: proceed with caution!

Comment: I tried this. The issue is when I provide the id explicitly, it successfully inserts that entry but it also changes the auto increment value of that column.
For example, the auto increment value is 1000.
and I insert the entry with id = 2000
After calling 
`
$this->em->persist(obj);
$this->em->flush(obj);
`
the auto increment value gets changed to 2001 which is not what I want.

Comment: My guess is this part happens on mysql level without doctrine incfluence then. Welp i don't think you prevent that happening then as long as the schema declares the field as auto_increment. Probably only solvable by querying for the current value, do the doctrine insert and execute a query to reset the value to what you got before. Will fail horribly if both flows insert at the same time though. At that point i would switch to an entirely different approach and get rid of this horrible design.

Comment: Yes I agree
This approach can fail at many spots.
Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: should $entityManager and $em be the same variable in your code?

Comment: @Joe thank you man! This works for me.  For cases when you need entity to have auto increment primary key ID but in some cases (eg automated import) you need to set the ID manually THIS SHOULD BE ACEPTED as the correct answer. Thanks dude

Comment: And BTW I did not have the problem with ID beeing incremented +1 - I am also using MySQL - the problem must be somewhere else...